# Relation between two measures and absolute continuous

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $\mu$ and $\rho$ be two measures on the same $\sigma$-algebra. Define $$\mathcal{E}=\{E|\mu(E^c)=0, E \quad\text{measurable}\}$$
>   and set $\gamma=\inf_{E\in\mathcal{E}}\rho(E)$.
>
> a) Show that there is a measurable $E_0$ in $\mathcal{E}$ that satisfies $\rho(E_0)=\gamma$ and
>
> b)Let $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ be the restriction of $\rho$ on $E_0$ and $E_0^c$, prove $\rho_1<<\mu,\rho_2\perp \mu$. You may assume that both $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ be two measures on the same $\sigma$-algebra.

I don't know how to show the existence in (a), it means $\rho$ obtains minimal value on $\mathcal{E}$, but I can't connect it with what I learn. I also don't know how to show absolute continuous in (b), but I can show $\rho_2\perp \mu$, which is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. By definition, there exists a sequence $(E_n)_n \subseteq \mathcal{E}$ such that $\varrho(E_n) \downarrow \gamma$. Consider $$E_0 := \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} E_n.$$
2. Let $A$ be a measurable set such that $\mu(A)=0$. In order to prove absolute continuity, we have to show $\varrho(A \cap E_0)=0$. Show that $\mu(A \cup E_0^c)=0$ and therefore $(A \cup E_0^c)^c \in \mathcal{E}$. Now use $\varrho(E_0) = \gamma \leq \varrho((A \cup E_0^c)^c)$.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. It turns out to be not that hard. I feel a little frustrated, since I still can't master those basic techniques after a one-term course.

Comment: @JohnZHANG Just keep trying. Solving exercises is the best way to get familiar with standard techniques.

Comment: For a), do I need to assume $E_n^c$ are disjoint? Since I need to make sure $E_0$ is in $\mathcal{E}$

Comment: @JohnZHANG Note that a countable union of sets of measures zero has again measure zero.